# how to convert select option to button in bundle product?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, bundle-product

I want to customize Bundle product template, convert select option to button "Add Item". Convert select,multiselect,checkbox, radio to button to add instead selection. Anyone have a solution or idea on this? How to achieve this?
Like this:
with select, radio:
[image: magento bundle product]

with select multi, checkbox:
[image: magento bundle product]
thanks for read.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to simply copy the .phtml templates that are used to generate the options, to your custom theme folder, and adjust as needed.

You will find (most of) them located here:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/
```

but special product types like bundles (and possibly downloadable) have them located in their respective module folders

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/
```